# Theano matrix multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, shared, theano

I have a piece of code that is supposed to calculate a simple
matrix product, in python (using theano). The matrix that I intend to multiply with is a shared variable.

The example is the smallest example that demonstrates my problem.

I have made use of two helper-functions. floatX converts its input to something of type theano.config.floatX
init_weights generates a random matrix (in type floatX), of given dimensions.

The last line causes the code to crash. In fact, this forces so much output on the commandline that I can't even scroll to the top of it anymore.

So, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
def floatX(x):
 return numpy.asarray(x,dtype=theano.config.floatX)

def init_weights(shape):
 return floatX(numpy.random.randn(*shape))

a = init_weights([3,3])
b = theano.shared(value=a,name="b")
x = T.matrix()
y = T.dot(x,b)
f = theano.function([x],y)
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for me. So my guess is that you have a problem with your blas installation. Make sure to use Theano development version:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions

It have better default for some configuration. If that do not fix the problem, look at the error message. There is main part that is after the code dump. After the stack trace. This is what is the most useful normally.

You can disable direct linking by Theano to blas with this Theano flag: blas.ldflags=

This can cause slowdown. But it is a quick check to confirm the problem is blas.

If you want more help, dump the error message to a text file and put it on the web and link to it from here.

Comment: How do I set this flag?
Just
    python -c 'blas.ldflags='

Comment: As it worked for you accepting the answer is great. For other, to set Theano flags, one way it to define the OS environement variable `THEANO_FLAGS=blas.ldflags=...`. Doc for more detail and alternative http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html